# Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease FAILED React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, native, release

R8 is the new Android code shrinker. If you experience any issues, please file a bug at
https://issuetracker.google.com, using 'Shrinker (R8)' as component name. You can
disable R8 by updating gradle.properties with 'android.enableR8=false'.
Current version is: 1.4.94 (build 390954928f0db9c3b888a367f7f128ce3bbfb160 from go/r8bot (luci-r8-ci-archive-0-5g74)).

D8: Program type already present: com.oney.WebRTCModule.BuildConfig

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task `:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease`.

> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete

The `android.enableR8=false` is as it is but still after running `./gradlew bundleRelease` it is showing me this error.